# Shiny Downloadhander tar output

Tags: r, shiny, tar, shiny-server

I am experiencing some strange tar() behavior when using it within Shiny's downloadhandler. Can you guys please take a look and offer some feedback?

```
output$splitDNLDnrow = downloadHandler(
filename =    paste(tools::file_path_sans_ext(input$file1$name),
               "_splitby",as.character(input$splitNrow),".tar", sep = ""),
content = function(file){
# Split Dataframe into list of segmented dataframes "datlist"
tempdat = dat()

chunk = input$splitNrow
  n = nrow(tempdat)
  r = rep(1:ceiling(n/chunk),each=chunk)[1:n]
  tempdat$brk = r
  r = unique(r)
  datlist = split(subset(tempdat,select = setdiff(names(tempdat),"brk")), tempdat$brk)


# Create "asdf" folder in default directory to write files to.
# If the folder exists already, all contents are removed.
tdir = tempdir()
tdir = paste(tdir,"\\asdf",sep = "")
if(dir.exists(tdir) == TRUE){unlink(paste(tdir,"\\",dir(tdir), sep = ""))}else{dir.create(tdir)}

# Write Segmented files to temporary directory
  # Write pathnames for output files: "tempdir()\asdf\inputFilename_##.csv"
  # outfiles = paste(tdir,"\\",input$file1$name,"_",as.character(r),".csv", sep = "")
  basename = tools::file_path_sans_ext(input$file1$name)
  outfiles = paste(basename,"_",as.character(r),".csv", sep = "")
        outfiles = paste(tdir,"\\",outfiles, sep = "")
  # Write Files
  # lapply(1:length(datlist), function(i) write.csv(datlist[[i]],
  #                               file = outfiles,row.names = FALSE))
  for(i in 1:length(r)){
    splitdat = tempdat[tempdat$brk == r[i],]
    write.csv(splitdat, outfiles[i])
  }

  tar(tarfile = file, files = tdir) })
```

The expression works as intended, for the most part. 
However, when the tar-file is downloaded through the browser I find that it contains empty copies of all the folders in the "files = tdir" path. I have to click through all these empty folders to reach the final folder "tempdir()/asdf" to see the files created.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the appropriate tar expression so the output tar file only has the files in "tempdir()/asdf"??